Examples of random matrices that are not iid
There is a lot of literature on random matrices, however, in most of the sources that I have seen, the standard construction is by iid sampling of elements of the matrix. While it is natural from mathematical point of view I do not see practical interest in such construction: if an operator models some physical process, hardly it can be related by iid sampling of its elements in some specific coordinate system.

Could someone tell me in which applications random matrices with iid
sampling make a really reasonable model? (I guess that in some areas
iid sampling could be reasonable - like graphs/network/social
modelling - but I am not sure).

From Bayesian inference it is known that distributions on some classes of matrices are possible, like the Wishart distribution on positive definite matrices. For me it is
the opposite side of iid sampled matrices (which I find very "unstructured") - these are too "structured" and very fast there is a limit in modelling by standard tools (instead
of priors we start to use mixtures which are often barely interpretable (I mean the mixing parameters)) ...

I wonder if there is something in between - e.g. I start from some
operator (matrix) which  is deterministic and reasonable for
modelling and slowly increase its complexity by adding
randomizations (I prefer term 'jittering') that do not break initial
physical meaning.


In random matrix theory it is more common to consider models like the Gaussian unitary ensemble, etc., where the entries will not all be iid because of restrictions that the matrices be hermitian, etc.

For the last point, the simplest approach is to take the operator and add a random Hermitian operator. This is described by the Dyson Brownian motion process.

@WillSawin But what it means to add random Hermitian operator? At which point this could be interesting?

Oh I just mean take a matrix where the entires are iid Gaussian except for the condition that they be Hermitian, as Sam Hopkins said, and add it to your matrix. This seems like possibly the simplest model of 'jittering' a Hermitian matrix, and might be interesting for that reason, or see the literature on Dyson Brownian motion for reasons people have found this interesting in the past.

I am not convinced by the first paragraph: it is very natural to have a multivariate Gaussian which looks the same in all directions, and then that is given by i.i.d. Gaussians in each coordinate. Indeed, this is one motivation for GUE as a toy model!

@YemonChoi But what do you mean 'a gaussian' here. When we speak of a vector - yes I agree, but what do you mean by 'an operator' that looks the same in any direction? I am sure it is possible to give meaning to many things, I was wondering of an example that is motivated.

@WillSawin Yes, I agree that jittering without changing the class is reasonable, I indeed had never heard of Dyson Brownian motion. I wanted just to highlight that in my experience I had never met the need for random matrices apart of a few exotic cases (if we remove bayesian inference when some covariance is unknown - zero cases). I understand that RM could be a tool for proving many interesting results, but are there any physical processes from the real world that are modeled by truly random operators that have their components iid / or not iid (in some basis)?

Concerning physical applications, it's hard to find a treatment of quantum chaos that doesn't mention random matrix theory. The spectral densities of random matrix ensembles behave like those of quantum chaotic systems.

If I may be so presumptuous as to expand on the comment by @YemonChoi , a (linear) operator looking the same "in all directions" in this context can mean that for any matrix $A$ in the ensemble, also $U^{-1} A U$ is in the ensemble, with, say, any unitary rotation $U$. This becomes particularly interesting if one has more than one such operator, leading (in the large-$N$ limit) to the framework of free random variables.

@MichaelEngelhardt Thanks, this what I essentially asked in my question and this is new to me. I had a course on classical quantum mechanics a long time ago, so I remember that it was essentially about single particle in some field and no interactions between them, nor ensembles (this is closer to statistical mechanics). Would it be difficult for you to give some reference how GUE is used in quantum mechanics?

@FedorGoncharov - A nice short summary at an introductory level is given here. If you want a flavor of the kind of thing people publlsh these days in this direction, here is an application to non-abelian gauge theory.

Q: Are there any physical processes from the real world that are modeled by truly random operators that have their components iid / or not iid (in some basis)?
A widely studied example of a random matrix with components that are not i.i.d. is localization of waves by a random potential (Anderson localization). The Hamiltonian is then a banded random matrix, with the nonzero matrix elements clustered along the principal diagonal. Of course, this representation is then basis dependent, which is the essence of localization: eigenstates are confined to nearby lattice sites.
For an overview, see Random band matrices by Paul Bourgade.
Conversely, a system where the eigenstates are extended rather than localized is well described by a Hamiltonian that is statistically equivalent in any basis, which leads to the representation of i.i.d. Gaussian matrix elements.
